# Rotar un ImageButton en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

En el `header` de mi `NavigationView` he creado un `ImageButton` que cuando se pulse sobre el, cambie el menú que aparece en el `NavigationView`. Esta tarea funciona perfectamente, pero quiero que cuando se pulse esta `ImageButton`, la imagen que tiene dentro, gire 90º y cuando vuelvas a pulsar, vuelva a la posición original. Todo esto con una animación.

El resultado final seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado crearlo de la siguiente forma, pero no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar.

Un pequeño punto a destacar es que creo que el problema surje al introducir la animación dentro de evento `onClick()`, porque fuera de dicho evento, funciona perfectamente.

`nav_header.xml`: Es el `header` del `NavigationView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/admin"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Administración"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/select_menu"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_bottom"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navView;
private View header;
private ImageButton selectMenu;
private TextView admin;
private Animation left_90, bottom_90;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    left_90 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_90left);
    bottom_90 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_90bottom);

    if (navView != null) {
        header = navView.getHeaderView(0);
        selectMenu = (ImageButton) header.findViewById(R.id.select_menu);
        admin = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.admin);
        selectMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (admin.getText().equals("Administración")){
                    v.startAnimation(left_90);
                    navView.getMenu().clear();
                    navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_menu_admin);
                    admin.setText("Volver");
                } else if (admin.getText().equals("Volver")) {
                    v.startAnimation(bottom_90);
                    navView.getMenu().clear();
                    navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_menu_study);
                    admin.setText("Administración");
                }
            }
        });
        selectItemNavigationView(navView);
        selectItem(navView.getMenu().getItem(0));
    }

}
}
```

`rotate_90left.xml`: Este archivo aplicará el efecto de 90º de rotación hacia el sentido de las agujas del reloj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

`rotate_90bottom.xml`: Este archivo aplicará el efecto de 90º de rotación hacia el sentido contrario a las agujas del reloj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues mira, en mi caso personal ya no hago uso de animaciones desde XML por que desde la versión 4.X puedes usar las del ViewPropertyAnimator. Un ejemplo de rotación con esta propiedad es el siguiente:

```
View.animate().rotation(90).setDuration(2000);
```

Donde "view" seria el ImageButton que quieres girar.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de `onClick()`

usa :

```
selectMenu.startAnimation(left_90);
```

y

```
selectMenu.startAnimation(bottom_90);
```

es decir:

```
 selectMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (admin.getText().equals("Administración")){
                    selectMenu.startAnimation(left_90);
                    navView.getMenu().clear();
                    navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_menu_admin);
                    admin.setText("Volver");
                } else if (admin.getText().equals("Volver")) {
                    selectMenu.startAnimation(bottom_90);
                    navView.getMenu().clear();
                    navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_menu_study);
                    admin.setText("Administración");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Esta opción sería la más lógica, según toda la información que he encontrado por Internet, pero no se porque a mi no me funciona.